# Exponentials in $\operatorname{Fun}(\mathcal C^{\mathrm{op}}, \operatorname{Cat}_{\infty})$

Tags: higher-category-theory

Let $\mathcal C$ be a locally small $\infty$-category. In several places I encountered the claim that the functor $\infty$- category $\operatorname{Fun}(\mathcal C^{\mathrm{op}}, \operatorname{Cat}_{\infty})$
is Cartesian closed, with exponentials given by
$$G^F\colon c \mapsto \operatorname{Nat}(h_c\times F, G)$$
where $\operatorname{Nat}(-, -)$ denotes the $\infty$-category of natural transformations in $\operatorname{Fun}(\mathcal C^{\mathrm{op}}, \operatorname{Cat}_{\infty})$ (i.e. an enhancement of the mapping space in that category, a formal definition can be found in the paper of Gepner, Haugseng and Nikolaus) and where $h$ is the Yoneda embedding. I never found a proof of that result, though. Is anybody familiar with a reference for this claim?

Comment: I don't know a reference, but it should be as easy to understand as $1$-categorically : if $H = h_c$, then $G^F(c) = Map(h_c,G^F) = Map(h_c\times F, G)$; so this is the only formula that can work, and conversely this formula is compatible with the formation of (small) colimits, so it will work for any $H$

Comment: Yes that part I understand, but is it true that any such functor $H$ can be obtained as a colimit of representables?

Comment: That's a good question, I don't think so actually, because the $\infty$-category of functors to \mathcal $S$ is cocomplete, and the inclusion $Fun(C,\mathcal S)\to Fun(C,Cat_\infty)$  preserves those (because $\mathcal S\to Cat_\infty$ does, because it has a right adjoint which is the core functor). Actually an interesting question would be what $Nat(h_c,F)$ is (I pretended as though it worked just as for Yoneda, but it's not that clear actually). Good question, I hope someone more knowledgeable can help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of not leaving this question unanswered: the $\infty$-category $\operatorname{Cat}_{\infty}$ arises as a localisation of the presheaf $\infty$-category $\operatorname{Fun}(\Delta^{\mathrm{op}}, \mathcal S)$ in which the localisation functor commutes with finite products. By postcomposition, we thus find that $\operatorname{Fun}(\mathcal C^{\mathrm{op}},\operatorname{Cat}_\infty)$ arises as a localisation of $\operatorname{Fun}((\mathcal C\times\Delta)^{\mathrm{op}},\mathcal S)$ where the localisation functor preserves finite products. Since presheaf $\infty$-categories are cartesian closed, this means that $\operatorname{Fun}(\mathcal C^{\mathrm{op}},\operatorname{Cat}_\infty)$ is an exponential ideal in $\operatorname{Fun}((\mathcal C\times\Delta)^{\mathrm{op}},\mathcal S)$ and therefore in particular cartesian closed. Moreover, since this result implies that the exponential in $\operatorname{Fun}(\mathcal C^{\mathrm{op}},\operatorname{Cat}_\infty)$ is computed in $\operatorname{Fun}((\mathcal C\times\Delta)^{\mathrm{op}},\mathcal S)$, the desired formula follows from the well-known fact that the exponential in presheaf $\infty$-categories is computed according to the very same formula.